# Error on creating war using warbler

Tags: java, jruby, warbler

i have a jruby application, and use warbler to make war files of it. But everytime i ran `jruby -S rake war` The warbler throw an error, it said `can't convert nil to String` and the error is in rubyzip, it happened when rake invoked war:jar, so how can i fix it ?

do we have any other alternative to create war for jruby ? (beside the warbler)

below is what i had on my system.

```
jruby -version
jruby 1.3.0 (ruby 1.8.6p287) (2009-06-03 5dc2e22) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_20) [x86_64-java]

actionmailer (2.0.2)
actionpack (2.0.2)
activerecord (2.0.2)
activeresource (2.0.2)
activesupport (2.0.2)
gemcutter (0.5.0)
jruby-jars (1.5.1)
jruby-memcache-client (1.7.0)
jruby-rack (1.0.1)
json_pure (1.4.3)
rails (2.0.2)
rake (0.8.7)
rspec (1.2.6)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
sources (0.0.1)
warbler (1.1.0)

$: jruby -S rake war
** Invoke war (first_time)
** Execute war
** Invoke war:files (first_time)
** Execute war:files
** Invoke war:jar (first_time)
** Execute war:jar
rm -f prog.war
Creating prog.war
rake aborted!
can't convert nil into String
/Users/suprie/Opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyzip-0.9.4/lib/zip/zip.rb:1113:in `<<`
/Users/suprie/Opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyzip-0.9.4/lib/zip/zip.rb:1062:in `<<`
/Users/suprie/Opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rubyzip-0.9.4/lib/zip/ioextras.rb:125:in 
....
/Users/suprie/Opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/suprie/Opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/Users/suprie/Opt/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/suprie/Opt/jruby/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: Would be helpful to post the exact error and backtrace of what you are experiencing.  Also versions of things, e.g. JRuby, Rails, other gems

Comment: sorry, i tried to put the error trace on my post. but i guess i did something wrong so the error trace aren't properly formatted.

Comment: Reformatted it for you; is there more of that stack trace?  There's some "..." in there.  Not sure it will help.  One thing is that your version of rails is somewhat old.  Do you need to use that exact version?  You might consider upgrading to the latest 2.x and trying it.  You also have a pretty old version of JRuby, too.  I'm not sure how well-supported rails was on 1.3 of JRuby

Comment: hi, you were right. The problem was because of the old version of Jruby, i've upgraded the jruby to the latest ( 1.5.0 ) and it's worked  like charm.. Thank you

Comment: could one of you make an answer of the solution so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered please ?